# Filter a table with select input for a particular column

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, select, filter, html-table

I have a table with pagination and sorting implemented with footable jquery plugin. Now I want a particular column to be filtered with select input.

Here is part of the code:

```
  table class="footable table table-stripped" data-page-size="10" data-filter="#filter" id="example"
   thead
    tr
     th Problem Name
     th Hospital
     th Status / here i want to filter with select input
     th Availablity Slot Start Time
     th Availablity Slot End Time
   tbody
    - @bookings.each do |book|
     tr class="gradeX"
      td=book.problem.name
      td=book.hospital
      /----some code----- 
javascript:
 $(function(){
  $('.footable').footable();
 });
```

I have no idea how to implement it.
How do I filter them with jquery? Help me.

Comment: Can you describe this line ?   "filter a table with select input"

Comment: It should work like http://rbayliss.net/jquery-dropdown-table-filter

Comment: I do not understand what is the issue, the jQuery Dropdown Table Filter plugin you provided is well documented, why you just don't try it and then come back as well?